# Logging datetime with ms precision using NLog event context layout renderer

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, nlog, nlog-configuration

I am trying to log some audit information to a SQL Server 2008 table using NLog 2. In order to be able to pass parameters to the SQL insert query, I'm using LogEventInfo and the [Event Context Layout Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Event-Context-Layout-Renderer).

The logging itself works but the datetime is stored with only second precision. I want to be able to store with millisecond precision but have not found anything that shows me how to do this.

This is the C# code where I log the event:

```
private void LogMessage(DateTime requestDateTime)
{
    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my custom value");
    theEvent.Properties["RequestDate"] = requestDateTime;
}
```

This is the target I have in my NLog.config configuration:

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
      name="SqlLog"
      dbProvider="sqlserver"
      connectionString="server=localhost;database=Test;integrated security=sspi">
  <commandText>
    INSERT [dbo].[ApiLog]
    (
        [ServerName], [RequestDate]
    )
    VALUES (@ServerName, @RequestDate);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@ServerName" layout="${machinename}"/>
  <parameter name="@RequestDate" layout="${event-context:item=RequestDate}"/>
</target>
```

There is a workaround I have found using `theEvent.Properties["RequestDate"] = requestDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` but I would prefer not to have to do this because then you may run into problems with date time formatting and culture.

Does anyone know of a way that I can change the precision with config in NLog.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the EventContextLayoutRenderer uses `Convert.ToString` which will lose the precision you are looking for:

```
public class EventContextLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    //....

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        object value;

        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(this.Item, out value))
        {
            builder.Append(Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
}
```

As you probably know (and I'm not sure if it's helpful in your situation), but there is a Date layout where you can specify the format and/or a LongDate one which will provide something like `2014-01-01 12:12:12.1234`

**EDIT**

For what it's worth, you can add a customer layout renderer very easily

```
[LayoutRenderer("event-context-dateTime")]
public class DateTimeContextLayoutRenderer : EventContextLayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        object value;

        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(this.Item, out value))
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

And in your configuration

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="YourAssembly"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file"  fileName="c:\temp\NlogLayout.txt" 
     layout="${longdate} ${event-context-dateTime:item=RequestDate}" />
   ...
</nlog>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. If I implement my own LayoutRenderer then its still using a StringBuilder to build out the DateTime as a string. So there's no way to pass an actual DateTime into SQL through NLog. I've marked yours as the answer because it at least gives a cleaner solution than having to perform the formatting in the calling code.